# Are these formulas proper notation?

Tags: notation

Are these valid ways of expressing the same idea?

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \dots =  \sum_{x \in \mathbb N}  \frac{1}{2^x} = \sum_{x = 1 }^ \infty  \frac{1}{2^x}  = \sum_{x = 1 }^ {x\to\infty}  \frac{1}{2^x} = 1$$

The one that bothers me is the third one, it seems to imply that $x=\infty$ at some point, in other words it treats $\infty$ as a number.

The problem with 1,2 and 4 would be that the sum only approaches 1 but never actually gets there.

Yet, if you squint a little, they all look good.

Comment: It's just notations. Nothing really changes. (Except for the last equality, of course)

Comment: The third one is standard notation. (If it makes you feel better, think of it as saying $x\le\infty$.) It's the fourth I've never seen, I would advise against using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the third one is the correct one.

The first one is not exhaustive: you imagine it will go on with $\frac{1}{16}$, but it may as well be of the form $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+0+0+\cdots$.

In the second one you are assuming $0\notin \mathbb{N}$, which is not exactly standard, as Peano axioms put $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

For the fouth one, the precise form could be $$\lim_{y\to\infty}\sum_{x=1}^y\frac{1}{2^x},$$
which actually is the definition of $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^x}$.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth notation is non-standard (or at least unusual, I suppose, since I have never seen it in the literature). The third notation actually says what I think you mean by the fourth notation, namely, $x$ counts up through all positive integers, never actually reaching $\infty$ but never stopping at any finite value.

The standard interpretation of the first three notations (and the way I would interpret the fourth notation) is as the limit of the partial sum of the series, that is, you add up the terms of the series for $x=1,2,3,\ldots,n,$ which gives you a finite sum, and then you take the limit of this sum as $n\to\infty.$
The result is exactly $1.$
(This assumes a definition of $\mathbb N$ such that $0\not\in\mathbb N.$ If  $0\in\mathbb N$ then of course the sum is $2.$)